# Obtaining SerializationService, cloning through serialization

Tags: java, serialization, clone, hazelcast

Hello I need to implement cloning through serialization with Hazelcast. My domain model is using `IdentifiedDataSerializeable`. In order to implement it I am creating `DefaultSerializationService`, but now I need to specify the serialization factories.

My question is: The `SerializationService` has already been created for Hazelcast with all the factories.

Why should I create the serialization service again if Hazelcast already has got one.

Is it possible somehow to access the `SerializationService` that Hazelcast already is using in order to implement the cloning ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly. So you want to serialize these objects outside of `Hazelcast`? And you want to use Hazelcast's internal mechanisms like `SerializationService` to serialize them since they already implement `IdentifiedDataSerializeable`?

If so, Using `SerializationService` that way is not supported. `SerializationService` is a part of Hazelcast `SPI` that has no backward-compatibility guarantees. It is also not supported to use the `SerializationService` outside of Hazelcast.

In theory, you could take advantage of the `SerializationService` if you wanted to use it in a custom `Hazelcast` service that you're building, but again, the Service's API may change at anytime.

Other way of doing it inside of `Hazelcast`. When you call `ObjectDataOutput.writeObject()` then it will use whatever `Serializer` was configured.

If you're just trying to configure `IdentifiedDataSerializeable` have a look at the [manual](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-dataserializable) entry related to it.